# Multiple commands same CMD window

Tags: c#

Would it be possible to send multiple commands to the same CMD window?

example: user hits GO the code sends a startserver cmd command opening a game server in console mode.
When the user hits ban I want the program to send BAN to that same console window (the server's window).

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Comment: It sounds more like you should be spawning the game server process directly and redirecting the standard input/output of that process to your own program.  You'd then be able to send input to the program directly.

Comment: Thanks James Thorpe, I googled around a bit and found that that is most likely the solution :D. Please add it as an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: John Saunders, I apologize but it just feels wrong asking something without saying thank you.

Comment: @g3mini FYI when replying to comments, it's a good idea to tag people with the @ command, as I've done here, as it will send a notification to them - I just happened to re-look at this, otherwise I wouldn't have seen it again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than attempting to do everything through the external CMD process, you should instead spawn the game engine process yourself directly to give you more control.

During the startup of the process, use the [`RedirectStandardOutput`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.redirectstandardoutput%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [`RedirectStandardInput`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.redirectstandardinput(v=vs.110).aspx) properties to gain access to see the output and send commands to the game server.